# Can you get a line-in port on a MBA via an external device?

Tags: macbook-pro, audio

I have a macbook air and I really want to plug in my guitar to garage band, but unfortunately the air doesn't have a line-in port. My question is, is there an external device that can provide you a line-in port? Just like the way you can plug in headphones and use the headset's mic, instead of the built in one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Griffin iMic](http://www.griffintechnology.com/support/imic) is a great device for sound input and output via USB.